# images are not replacing while click the button

Tags: jquery, css

i have 3 buttons ,when click the one of those buttons the image is going to replace the old one.

i created buttons but it's not working

> jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.black-button').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#bar').attr('src','flash-red.png');
     }
 });

$('.red-button').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#bar').attr('src','flash-red.png');
     }
 });

$('.blue-button').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#bar').attr('src','flash-red.png');
     }
 });

$('.yellow-button').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#bar').attr('src','flash-red.png');
     }
 });
});
```

in the body i have written code for blinking and change the  images while click the button

> body

```
<div class="button-container">
                <button class="black-button"></button>
                <button class="red-button"></button>
                <button class="blue-button"></button>
                <button class="yellow-button"></button>
         </div>
```

```
<button id="flash-toggle" onclick="$('.bar1').toggleClass('blinking')">
    Toggle Blinking
</button>
```

In css apply the properties

> css

```
#btn-show {
    display: none;
}
.tgl
{
  display:inline;
}

   .bar1,.bar2{
    opacity: 0.002;;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    }
    @keyframes blinkingFrames {
    0% {opacity: 0.00;}
    50% {opacity: 1.00;}
    100% {opacity: 0.00;}
}

.blinking {
    animation-name: blinkingFrames;
    animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve], and also explain what exactly “not working” means. Did you at least check the browser console for errors?

Comment: your syntax is wrong: `.on('click', function() {}`

Comment: when  i click any one of those buttons image is not showing

Comment: while i change like this  .on('click', function() {} it's showing error on comma

Comment: Hi, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can use [SO Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: <img  id="bar" class="bar1" src="flash-red.png" alt="bar" >
        
        <button id="flash-toggle" onclick="$('.bar1').toggleClass('blinking')">
            Toggle Blinking
        </button>                      when click the red ,blue or other buttons  img id is needs to be changed but not changing.

Comment: the actual purpose of this program is need to replace the images in  <img id="bar"> when click the other buttons images need to be changed but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the coments, your syntax was wrong. Should be:

`$(element).on(event, function)`

See below working code:

1. click on a color button
2. click on "toggle"
3. See image blinking

I do not have your image, so the linked one is from wikimedia. Replace it with the image you want/need.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.black-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').prop('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg/440px-The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg');

  });

  $('.red-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').prop('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg/440px-The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg');

  });

  $('.blue-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').prop('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg/440px-The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg');

  });

  $('.yellow-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').prop('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg/440px-The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg');

  });
})
```

```css
button {
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
}

.black-button {
  background: black
}

.red-button {
  background: red
}

.blue-button {
  background: blue
}

.yellow-button {
  background: yellow
}

#btn-show {
  display: none;
}

.tgl {
  display: inline;
}

.bar1,
.bar2 {
  opacity: 0.002;
  ;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes blinkingFrames {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.00;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.00;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.00;
  }
}

.blinking {
  animation-name: blinkingFrames;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="black-button"></button>
  <button class="red-button"></button>
  <button class="blue-button"></button>
  <button class="yellow-button"></button>
</div>

<button id="flash-toggle" onclick="$('.bar1').toggleClass('blinking')">
    Toggle Blinking
</button>
<img id="bar" class="bar1" src="flash-red.png" alt="bar" >
```

Comment: Thank you very much but images are not blinking. I supposed to do replace the image in the <img id="bar" class="bar1" src="flash-red.png" alt="bar" >. when i click the red button red button image going to replace with  src="flash-red.png". Can you help me for doing this one .Thank ou

Comment: Updated the answer for you. Now it is blinking

Comment: Hi Unamata, i created 3 divs. Every div having these 4 color buttons. When click the button that corresponding image appering and blinking but thae code become long. i tried to use if condition  and has method for instead of writng always same code like this .................................................................... $('.black-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').prop('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg/440px-The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent.jpg');

  });  but it's not working properly. How can i do.Thank you